# jquery select child by class, on child-click toggle the parents class

Tags: jquery

I am trying to select an element by `class`, and when it is clicked the parent is toggled.

**HTML:**

`

```
great-grandparent <div class='section' id='section-18'>
   grandparent       <div class='docs'>
          parent        <div class='octowrap'>
                *          <a class='octothorpe' href='#section-18'>#</a>
```

`

```
$('octothorpe').closest('div.section').click(function() {
                    $(".fold").toggle(500);
                      console.log('fold', $('.fold').length);

                });
});

console.log("closest", $('.octothorpe').closest('div.section').length);
```

`

```
<style>
.fold {
    display: None;
}
</style>
```

`

q1 answered <<*Neither work, so how do I test that the class element is being selected?
Is there a standard console log message I can output? (I tried looking at firefox inspector, but couldnt tell if its getting selected or not.  How do I test this straightforward way?(ie without change the color, etc.. just in log?)* )>>

Am I chaining functions click and toggle correctly? 
Only the child can be clicked, (octothorpe is a href), but the parent .section is what needs to be toggle?

**for the code below:**

console.log.
(For test of parents) closest = 1 , never changes.
(For test of fold) fold increments each time clicked.  But the toggleClass has no effect even with preventDefault(). Does style `display:None` not work in this situation?

`

```
$(function() {
  $(".octothorpe").click(function(e) {
                             e.preventDefault();
                             var sector = $(this).closest("div.section");
                             sector.toggleClass(".fold");
                             //sector.(".fold").toggle();
                             console.log('fold', $('.fold').length);
                         });
  });

console.log("closest", $('.octothorpe').closest('div.section').length);
```

---

Hi Thanks to all so far.  After some fiddling ive figured I cannot just select the great-grandparent, but the parent sibling and grandparent sibling.  If I just select the great-grandparent class then the element itself is essentially lost as I cannot bring it back!

Therefore, I tried the more selective code below.  However, neither hide or slideUp/Down as below appear to do anythin.  The console.log output shows the fold class incrementing so the elements are being selected.

Whats wrong with this code?

`

```
$(function(){
  $('.octothorpe').on({
                          click:function(e){
                              e.preventDefault();
                              var pfold =$(this).closest('.octowrap').siblings('p');
                              var cfold =$(this).closest('docs').siblings('.code');
                              $pfold=$(pfold); $cfold=$(cfold);
                              //$pfold.hide();
                              //$cfold.hide();

                              if (!$pfold.hasClass("fold") && !$cfold.hasClass("fold")) {
                                  $cfold.slideUp().addClass('fold');
                                  $pfold.slideUp().addClass('fold');
                                  console.log('fold', $('.fold').length);
                              }
                              else {

                                  cfold.slideDown().removeClass('fold');
                                  pfold.slideDown().removeClass('fold');
                              }    
                          }
                      });
```

});

`

`

Comment: Just place a console.log inside the click function and see if it's outputted in the console when you click the element ?

Comment: what do you mean by 'code-fold' ?

Comment: @NeilS it a code-doc; the element holds code/doc.  I just want to hide the element on click... ie code-fold.

Answer (score 1):

```
console.log($('.section').length);
```

will tell you how many elements are being selected. If you want to know if the `.fold` selector is working, place

```
console.log($('.fold').length);
```

in your click function.

Comment: The first comment, prints by default 1 on page load.  The .fold does not output, ie not being toggled.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the .parent() method.

so consider:

```
<div class="parent">
  <a href="#" class="child">click me</a>
</div>
```

js would be:

```
$(function(){
  $('.child').on({
    click:function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      //stop it from refreshing the page

      $(this).parent().toggle();
      //$(this) is the what you clicked on - <a class="child">
      //.parent() is the <div class="parent">
      //.toggle() show/hide the .parent()
    }
  });
});
```

Now this code is kinda dumb. Since you're hiding the parent, it means you're automatically hiding the child with it. So .toggle() is stupid. A better method would be:

```
$(function(){
  $('.child').on({
    click:function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      //stop it from refreshing the page

      $(this).parent().hide();
      //$(this) is the what you clicked on - <a class="child">
      //.parent() is the <div class="parent">
      //.hide() hide the .parent()
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: thanks for the tip about hiding the child with the parent.  the .hide() on the parent works, but it does remove the child as well.  i worked on it a little further and found that I need to be more specific in selecting elements, but still no luck with hide() or slide() functions

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have Sections on one container and the anchors on another container (as it makes sense if you are going to use them like an index / list of content) I would go for this:

```
$(".octothorpe").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var sectorhash = $(this).attr("href");
    $sector = $(sectorhash);
    if (!$sector.hasClass("fold")) {
        $sector.slideUp().addClass("fold");
    }
    else {
        $sector.slideDown().removeClass("fold"); 
    }
});
```

Comment: hi this helped, but I have a special select context parent sibling and grandparent sibling, but still dont have it working